# mongodb get element in multi array

Tags: python, mongodb

I have mongodb document like this:

```
{
    "post":[
        {
            "name": "post1",
            "part": [
                {
                    "name": "part1",
                    ...
                },{
                    "name": "part2",
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },{
            "name": "post2",
            "part": [
                {
                    "name": "part3",
                    ...
                },{
                    "name": "part4",
                    ...
                }
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want get output like this:

```
{
    "post": [
        {
            "part":[
                {
                    "name": "part2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

my query like this:

```
db.find_one({"_id": 123},{
    "post.%s.part.%s.name" % (0, 1) : 1
})
```

I known index of list post (is 0) and part (is 1)

I can't get by index of output, can you help me get element of array ?
I have try **$slice**, but how to query with **$slice** in multi part of array
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Projection can't project out specific elements except by matching with $. You can restrict to just the field `"post.part.name"` (but still getting the field value for each element of the bottom-level array).

Comment: I had success get that field with this query: {
 'xyzhack': 1, # hack filter
 'post': {"$slice": [post_index, 1]},
 'post.part.name': {"$slice": [part_index, 1]}
} , I add xyzhack field don't exists because I don't known why mongodb response all data without this field